# Unexpected rounding when using ISNULL in sybase sql anywhere

Tags: sql, type-conversion, sqlanywhere

I have to work with a legacy system based on SQL Anywhere 5, db access layer is in C++ using embedded SQL. The problem I have is not really a C++ problem, but embedded SQL forces us to SQL statements which cannot be dynamically generated. There are many tables containing a lot of columns having the datatype `double`. Though the main application expects these columns to be not `NULL`, there are no `NOT NULL` contraints on most of this columns. To avoid application crashes, we use a lot of `ISNULL` in our SQLs. For example, instead of just writing

```
SELECT d1,d2,d3,d4 FROM table1;
```

we write

```
SELECT ISNULL(d1,0),ISNULL(d2,0),ISNULL(d3,0),ISNULL(d4,0) FROM table1;
```

So far, problem solved, everything seems fine - we thought. Now, we have found, that, when for example `d1` contains 1.2345678987654321 in one row, then

```
SELECT d1 ...
```

results in

```
1.2345678987654321
```

but

```
SELECT ISNULL(d1,0) ...
```

results in

```
1.234567
```

The reason for this seems to be that when you call ISNULL with a double and a number like 0, there happens some type conversion of both arguments of ISNULL to `NUMBER(30,6)` first, so d1 is cutted to 6 decimals. Simple fix is here

```
SELECT ISNULL(d1,CAST(0 AS DOUBLE)) ...
```

This will give the expected `1.2345678987654321` again, but it results in very lengthy SQL statements:

```
SELECT ISNULL(d1,CAST(0 AS DOUBLE)),ISNULL(d2,CAST(0 AS DOUBLE)),ISNULL(d3,CAST(0 AS DOUBLE)), ISNULL(d4,CAST(0 AS DOUBLE))
```

So we tried to find a shorter way to write a DOUBLE zero literally in SQL:

`SELECT ISNULL(d1,0e0)...` or `SELECT ISNULL(d1,0.0)...`

does **not** work, gives  1.234567 again.

`SELECT ISNULL(d1,SIN(0))...` or `SELECT ISNULL(d1,1e-307)...`

works both, yields correct 1.2345678987654321, but seems both very ugly just for writing a 0.

So here is the question: **any ideas on how to write this shorter / more readable / avoid the problem totally?** Remember, neither generating SQL statements is an option under our constraints, nor is changing the DB schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no sure if it will work for v5 
try to set the database option to treat floats as doubles  via sql
run the query

```
set option FLOAT_AS_DOUBLE = 'ON'
```

if you want it to hold for the current connection only use

```
set TEMPORARY option FLOAT_AS_DOUBLE = 'ON'
```

you can then try to use your query's first version

Comment: I think this should be SET OPTION FLOAT_AS_DOUBLE = 'ON', otherwise you get a syntax error immediately. I tried both variants of the statement, from isql and from embedded sql, and I get the error message  invalid option 'FLOAT_AS_DOUBLE' -- no PUBLIC setting exists.

Comment: Having a look into the docs, I found FLOAT_AS_DOUBLE in the manuals of SQL Anywhere 5.5.4, but not in earlier versions like 5.5. Unfortunately, all our existing database files were created with an older version (migration to a newer version is definitely not an option I have). Anyone having another idea?